# Flex 3: How do I get the DataGridColumn's dataField in its ItemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3, itemrenderer, datafield

I'm trying to reach the dataField of a DataGridColumn in the itemRenderer. Below is the dataGrid:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable] public var weeksOfMoth:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {monday:30, tuesday:31, wednesday:1, thursday:2, friday:3, saturday:4, sunday:5},
                {monday:6, tuesday:7, wednesday:8, thursday:9, friday:10, saturday:11, sunday:12},
                {monday:13, tuesday:14, wednesday:15, thursday:16, friday:17, saturday:18, sunday:19}, 
                {monday:20, tuesday:21, wednesday:22, thursday:23, friday:24, saturday:25, sunday:26}, 
                {monday:27, tuesday:28, wednesday:29, thursday:30, friday:1, saturday:2, sunday:3}
            ]);
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{weeksOfMoth}" >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="view.DateRenderer" dataField="monday" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="view.DateRenderer" dataField="tuesday" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="view.DateRenderer" dataField="wednesday" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="view.DateRenderer" dataField="thursday" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="view.DateRenderer" dataField="friday" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="view.DateRenderer" dataField="saturday" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="view.DateRenderer" dataField="sunday" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

And this is my ItemRenderer:

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >
    <mx:Box >

                    <!-- How do I get the dataField here?? -->
        <mx:Label text="{data[dataField]}" /> 
    </mx:Box>
</mx:Canvas>
```

In the set data function of the itemRenderer, I receive an entire week (which is ok), but the itemRenderer doesn't know which day to use because the dataField is unknown. Does anyone know how to reach this dataField in the itemRenderer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment by www.Flextras.com helped me to find the solution. I can indeed use `listData.dataField`, but first the `IDropInListItemRenderer` class needs to be implemented.

The final `ItemRenderer`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" implements="mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
            import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;


            // Internal variable for the property value.
            private var _listData:DataGridListData;

            // Make the listData property bindable.
            [Bindable("dataChange")]

            // Define the getter method.
            public function get listData():BaseListData
            {
              return _listData;
            }

            // Define the setter method,
            public function set listData(value:BaseListData):void
            {
              _listData = DataGridListData(value);
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Box width="80%" height="80%" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
        <mx:Label text="{data[_listData.dataField]}" />
    </mx:Box>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [DataGridListData](http://www.few.vu.nl/~eliens/assets/flex3/langref/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridListData.html) class, which is passed into the renderer.  It contains a dataField property.

I'm pretty sure this should work:

```
<mx:Label text="{data[listData.dataField]}" />
```

Comment: This doesn't compile: "1120: Access of undefined property listData". It's probably a flex2 solution, but I'm using Flex3

Comment: As you discovered, this has nothing to do w/ Flex 2.  Many classes already implement the IDropInListItemRenderer interface.  Off topic; You should consider re-working your itemRenderer to use less containers.  Why not just use a Label?  Do you really need the addition 2 containers?

Comment: It's actually only a part of the entire renderer, in my actual code it really does need the containers. But you're right, the example used here can be smaller.

Comment: I'm glad you got it worked out.  if you think my answer helped you solve the issue, feel free to show some love and give my answer a vote. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to implement the IDropInListItemRenderer.
This is enough:

```
data[ ( listData as DataGridListData ).dataField ]
```

The concrete listData is of type DataGridListData, but the property itself is typed to BaseListData, since a renderer can be used in various scenarios. However, in this scenario we know it's DataGridListData, therefore we can simply cast it to access the dataField property.

Comment: I made my control more generic, and added a type check: `if (listData is DataGridListData) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for a Spark based item renderer in a MX AdvancedDataGrid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                                  width="100%"
                                  >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[               
            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;

            override public function set data( value:Object):void {             
                var latency:Number = value[ ( this.listData as DataGridListData).dataField] as Number;

                lbl.text = Utils.formatLatency( latency);
                if( latency > 1000000) { // 1s => error
                    lbl.setStyle( "backgroundColor", 0xFF8080);
                } else if( latency > 100000) { // 100ms => warning
                    lbl.setStyle( "backgroundColor", 0xFFFF80);
                } else if( latency > 0){ // low latency
                    lbl.setStyle( "backgroundColor", 0x80FF80);
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Label id="lbl" width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" textAlign="right" paddingRight="5"/>
</s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:
just use the properties

- `advancedDataGridListData` in MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderers
- `dataGridListData`in MXDataGridItemRenderer

  to access that information.

Answer (score 0):

For an average GridItemRenderer it's a

```
column.dataField
```

So, in your case this should work:

```
<s:Label text="{data[column.dataField]}" />
```